# Permission Denied in IE w/ iDispatch DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET

Tags: javascript, activex, internet-explorer, atl, ole

I have an ActiveX control that I've written using ATL, and am running into a somewhat serious and confusing problem. When iDispatch::Invoke is called with DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT/METHOD everything is fine. When I return a value to the IE javascript, after a method call of a VT_BSTR with a valid BSTR, it works fine.

But when  I try:

`var stringValue = Object.stringValue;`

which calls iDispatch invoked with the DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET flag, and I set the return value to VT_BSTR with a valid BSTR (the exact same one i use with the method calls), I get a permission denied error box in IE.

When I return various other datatypes (longs, integers, bools, ...etc) to the IE javascript, it works fine (with the propertyGet() method). I only get permission denied when returning VT_BSTR.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your get method implementation?  I assume you're not returning E_ACCESSDENIED.

Comment: Howdy,

    pvarResult->bstrVal = (BSTR)c;
    pvarResult->vt = VT_BSTR;
    if (wFlags == DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET) 
     return S_OK;


as a note I just placed the if wflags == DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET statement in a few days ago to make sure things were returning S_OK.

this is a relly confusing issue for me.. i've poured over the idispatch bits on msdn and not found to much to indicate what i'm doing wrong.

also on debugging the bstr is valid.. and the same code block works when  dispatch_method is set in wflags..

Comment: Sorry on the formating with that.


pvarResult->bstrVal = (BSTR)c;

 pvarResult->vt = VT_BSTR; 

if (wFlags == DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET) 
return S_OK

Comment: You can just edit your post to add the code in a nice formatted way.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment above, you're casting c to a BSTR.  What is c?  If you're not actually calling [SysAllocString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx) to create the BSTR, that could very well be the source of your problem.

Consider using CComBSTR or CComVARIANT to aide you in the process, and also please read [Eric's complete guide to BSTR semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx).

Comment: I've tried SysAllocString in the past for that portion of code, and gave it shot again with the same permission denied error...


what a headache yish

i've also tried CComVARIANT /  CComBSTR with no luck ..

Comment: Can you post a larger part of your code?  What you've got there should be fine, but it looks like you're perhaps doing it wrong.  Also include your IDL definition.

Comment: I'll see if i can put up anything more, but for the most part that's all there is...


as for the IDL file it's rather simple the methods I'm returning aren't defined in the idl..

the methods called with property_method aren't defined in the idl file either and work fine.. (filling out getidsofnames on our own seems to work fine)


there's probably something really odd I'm missing and need to keep toying with.

Comment: I'd bet, sadly that's not a something that's possible with this project.

plus I assume the issue is in a different potion of the code ... as propertyget, and propertyput do work for not bstr values..

I'll update this when i figure something out so the world can be a little less confused.